# messageSource is not being autowired by spring

Tags: spring

I am trying to get the message from my message properties file

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basenames">
<list>
<value>mymessage</value>
</list>
</property>
</bean>

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;

public class Test{

@Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;
    public MessageSource getMessageSource() {
        return messageSource;
    }
    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

public void draw()
    {

    System.out.println(this.messageSource.getMessage("name",null,"default",null));`enter code here`
    }}
```

in that i am getting null pointer exception

but when i have changed the code and implemented the MessageSourceAware in test class then its working fine. evenafter when i removed the @autowired annotation and the bean id defination itself.

Comment: but always the default value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my declaration in the dispatcher context "servlet-context.xml" :

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource"  class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <beans:property name="fileEncodings" value="UTF-8"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Change the class name from `class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource` to `class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`

And why your basename property is empty?